# Cannot run any command from PHP-FPM with Symfony Process

Tags: php, symfony, process

The following code gives me a 127 error code (command not found). I run the script within a PHP-FPM chroot.

I tried other commands, all give me the 127 error code. Any ideas why?

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

 $process = new Process(['ls', '-lsa']);
 $exitCode = $process->run();
 echo $exitCode;
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Because the PHP is not inheriting an environment, and more specifically a path. Try `/bin/ls`

That might not work either if php-fpm is running a chroot jail. Or on a MS-Windows machine.

Answer (score -2):

You need install the package first.

This package can be installed through Composer.

```
composer require symfony/process
```